# What does java.awt.FontFormatException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, awt

I need to create a font from a file, but sometimes I get an unexpected exception. It is thrown really strange because I can try to load one file several times and in one moment this exception is fired.
The stacktrace of this one looks like the following:

```
Caused by: java.awt.FontFormatException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:614)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:219)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:199)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.createFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2356)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:621)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1225)
```

I try to load the font that way:

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
    File fontFile = new File("arial.ttf");
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile); // I get an exception on this line

}
```

How can I fix that and why this happens?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Have you tried a more recent version?

Comment: @VGR I am using Java 11.

Comment: I’m looking at the source of sun.font.TrueTypeFont … unfortunately the code discards the stack trace information for that NullPointerException, so this is going to be quite difficult to troubleshoot.  I would try a different font;  there are many that look similar to Arial.

Comment: @VGR The point is this issue happens with different fonts and it comes in an occasional way.

Comment: It may very well be a bug in Java 11.  If you can use a later version (current version is 19, and Java 20 will be released next week), I would try that.